# Proving that $\{p\to q, p\to \neg q\}\Rightarrow\neg p$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

> Prove the following: $\{p\to q, p\to \neg q\}\Rightarrow\neg p$, that is, prove that $\neg p$ is a tautological consequence of $\{p\to q, p\to \neg q\}$

(Note: I write $0,1$ instead of $F,T$.)

Suppose the premises are true and the conclusion is false, so:

$p=1,p\to q=1,p\to \neg q=1$

Place $p=1$ in premises: $1\to q=1$ so $q=1$.

Place $p=q=1$ in $p\to \neg q=1$ and we get: $1\to0=1$ contradiction.

Thus the conclusion must be true.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: "In logic, a tautology is a formula that is true in every possible interpretation." ... since yours is not a "formula", it is not a tautology.  I would say the question should be: prove that this is a valid rule of deduction.

Comment: It could be that something was lost in translation.. Could it be also called "prove this is a tautological implication"? @GEdgar

Comment: The word tautology is only applicable to statements, what you have here is not a statement, as it has been observe. The appropriate term is 'tautological consequence'.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. What you need to do is check that any assignment of truth values that ends up making all the premises true, is such that $\neg p$ will also be true. In other words, check that a in truth table for the statements $p\to q, p\to \neg q$ and $\neg p$, whenever there are $1$'s in both premises, there is also a $1$ in $\neg p$.

Comment: @GitGud it's like a proof by contradiction, so we can avoid truth tables.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's correct.

Comment: @GitGud The original post's use of tautology was fine, I think. The expression $(p\Rightarrow q \land p \Rightarrow \lnot q) \Rightarrow p$ is a statement with variables p and q, and it is indeed a tautology (i.e. true for any p and q).

Comment: @aes But the OP didn't ask about $((p\to q)\land (p\to \neg q))\to p$, he asked about $\{p\to q, p\to \neg q\}\models \neg p$ which is different (even ignoring the negation which you forgot). One is a metastatement, the other statement. Metastatements cannot be tautologies. **Edit:** One can interpret $\implies$ as either $\models$ or $\to$ here, but $\to$ simply doesn't work as it wouldn't yield a proper formula (see GEdgar's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130879/proving-that-p-to-q-p-to-neg-q-rightarrow-neg-p?noredirect=1#comment2308492_1130879)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{p\to q, p\to\neg q\}\vdash \neg p$$

We know $q$ is true whenever $p$ is true and $q$ is false whenever $p$ is true, so that means that $q$ is simultaneously true *and* false whenever $p$ is true.   However, that is contradictory, so thus we have proof that $p$ can never be true, and therefore must be false.

$$\begin{align}
&(p \to q)\wedge (p\to \neg q)
\\ \Updownarrow & \qquad\text{: implication equivalence}
\\ &(\neg p\vee q)\wedge (\neg p \vee \neg q)
\\ \Updownarrow & \qquad\text{: distribution}
\\ & \neg p \vee (q\wedge \neg q) & \iff p\to (q\wedge \neg q)
\\ \Updownarrow & \qquad\text{: a contradiction}
\\ & \neg p \vee \bot
\\ \Updownarrow & \qquad\text{: disjunction's identity}
\\ & \neg p
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that either q or ~q.

If p, then (p and ~q) or (p and q).

In other words,

If ~[(p and ~q) or (p and q)], then ~p.

Thus:

If ~(p and ~q) and ~(p and q), then ~p.

That's:

If p => q and p => ~q, then ~p.

Answer (score 1):

Recall $\lnot p$ means $p \to \bot$ and $p \to \lnot q$ means $p \to (q \to \bot)$.

So: Assume $p$. Then, from $p \to q$, we have $q$. Also, from $p \to (q \to \bot)$, we have $q \to \bot$. Finally, from $q$ and $q \to \bot$, we have $\bot$. So we have $p \to \bot$, as desired. The only inference rule used is modus ponens.

This also shows that the implication in question is constructively valid. In particular does not rely on assuming $p \lor \lnot p$, $q \lor \lnot q$, or any similar version of the law of the excluded middle.